# Flutter - IconThemeData. Icon color changes for dark mode but doesn't change for light mode in Drawer()

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-theme

IconTheme Color doesn't change in light mode for the icons in drawer but changes color accordingly in dark mode.

[image: Image For Reference]